# Android Object get Jagged at the border

Tags: opengl, android, 3d, opengl-es, 3d-meshes

I am new to OpenGL ES 1 in android. My 3D Model border getting Jagged. Please help me to look like a smooth border instead of jagged.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gq83.png

```
private class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public Renderer() {
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setZOrderOnTop(true);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL10.GL_ONE);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        mViewWidth = (float)w;
        mViewHeight = (float)h;
        gl.glViewport(0,0,w,h);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, mViewWidth/mViewHeight, 0.1f, 100f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER); 

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        //draw_model
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        if(mOrigin != null && mRotate != null) {
            gl.glTranslatef(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mOrigin.z);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
            gl.glRotatef(mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        }

        if(mModel != null) {
            mModel.draw(gl);
            if(!RendererView.textureFileName.equals(""))
                mModel.bindTextures(mContext, gl);
        }

        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        if(isPictureTake) {

            w = getWidth();
            h = getHeight();
            b = new int[w*(y+h)];
            bt = new int[w*h];

            IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.wrap(b);
            ib.position(0);
            gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);
            createBitmapFromGLSurface(context);
            isPictureTake = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why r u using ES 1? ES 1 doesn't support programmable pipe line, is there any specific reason?

Comment: @Tofu_Craving_Redish_BlueDragon No reason, When I start to make my app then I mainly found ES 1 examples, you can recommend me to which version should I try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you were using ES 2.0 you can do something like GL_LINE_SMOOTH then the line will get smoothed out themselves tutorials on that [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1669-how-to-render-anti-aliased-lines-with-textures-in-ios-4/).

- Solution 00 : If you still want o use ES 1.0 still, I recommend what Lasse said in chat; draw anti-aliased texture then render it as your line.
- Solution 01 : Another easier way to do so will be preparing "anti-aliased" texture image with alpha value then draw it where you want to have "smooth line" (Prepare blurred square picture. Then resize/draw it where you want to have "smooth line").

  [image] (example of "smooth" texture that can be used for Solution 01)

But really both of them are same in nature; prerender texture for the effect you want, then draw it when you need it.